# Some nodes totally inaccessible

Tags: views, nodes, database

A great many of my nodes are not showing up at all on their node page (e.g. mysite.com/node/1234) but they are showing up in views, and they do exist in the database. What could cause a node to be unable to be viewed or edited on its node page, but still show up in Views and the database?

To clarify, "Not showing up at all" means I get a 404. I have cleared all caches.

Comment: is your site trying to use clean_urls ? Is it enabled in htaccess?

Comment: Did you do any manual SQL inserts or updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked it down.

`Node_load()` was dying whenever the query it was trying to run, failed. The query failed because it was joined on the UID of the author, and some users had been deleted. Lists of content that didn't use `node_load()` yielded the node's info without incident.